# Java: PrintWriter and newlines in a string

Tags: java, string, io

My question is pretty straight forward, if I have a single long string with alot of "\n" newlines within it, i.e:

```
strings = "Hey\nThere\nFriend\n"
```

And use a PrintWriter in Java to do the following:

```
PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
save.println(strings);
save.close();
```

Will the file I end up with be formatted with the \n? i.e the file will have:

```
Hey
There
Friend
```

Or will it have:

```
Hey\nThere\nFriend
```

If it's the latter, can someone guide me on how I might change my code (and understanding of how PrintWriter works) to create the former output?

Comment: It's the former. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, `\n` will work but only for Unix based OS.   Windows based OS use `\r\n` as separator.

You should avoid using specific OS line separator if you want to write a portable code.
Favor `System.lineSeparator()` to not be OS dependent.
Note also that `PrintWriter` provides `println()` to achieve a break line that is not OS dependent (even if it is not necessary useful for you use case)

Comment: Yep, just checked this on my Windows system, \n resulted in a single line but using System.lineSeparator() provided the correct output. Updating my code to reflect this, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will get a text file containing a single text line `Hey\nThere\nFriend\n` followed by your operating system new-line sequence (inserted by `println()`).

The meaning of `\n` depends on the operating system and possibly the text editor. On Linux `\n` usually will be interpreted as new-line sequence but on Windows the new-line sequence is `\r\n` so most text editors (e.g. native Notepad) will display a single `HeyThereFriend` line.

Comment: Yeah, just checked this and that is the case. Thank you for clarifying this as I had no idea

Answer (score 0):

On windows platform \n means char(13) +Char(10) you can use

```
String nl = Character.toString ((char) 13)+Character.toString ((char) 10);  
String strings = "Hey"+nl+"There"+nl+"Friend"+nl;
System.out.print(strings);
```